# How to change VSCode's clang-format extension's indent to 4?

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang-format

clang-format command line allows defining indentation width, e.g.

```
clang-format -style="{IndentWidth: 4}"  myfile.cpp
```

I installed clang-format extension to VSCode on Ubuntu linux, I do not see indent configuration at the extension configuration.

Is there a way to make the extension to take the indent of 4?

Comment: Which one of tens of clang-format extension?

Answer (score 0):

Short solution: Create a `.clang-format` at the project root with the following content:

```
# .clang-format
IndentWidth: 4
```

---

The [vscode-clang-format](https://github.com/xaverh/vscode-clang-format) seems unmaintained, however, the [clangd](https://github.com/clangd/vscode-clangd) extension for vscode comes with a default formatter support. And according to the [clangd repo's README](https://github.com/clangd/vscode-clangd?tab=readme-ov-file#formatting), the formatting is controlled by the  `.clang-format` file at the project root. Here's the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html), in case you need it.

Might be a little late, but hopefully this could be helpful.

Answer (score -2):

In clang-format extension settings you can use "Clang-format: Style" to give a specific option.

Example :

> {IndentWidth: 4}